# VimPlugin cursor does not update position on click

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

I am using vim plugin in VSCode. Sometimes, when I am in normal mode, I like to use my mouse to navigate, especially, if it is a big file. So I scroll to the new place, click there and try to begin editing my code by going back to the insert mode. However, when I use the insert mode, the cursor goes back to where it was before.

Vim cursor does not seem to remember the position of the new cursor updated on click. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, I'm pretty sure that's a bug as there's no reason for this to be a feature, as far as I can tell...

Comment: I discovered the same thing starting today. Pretty much breaks the entire experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this thread on [github](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/4405#issuecomment-697927697).

> As for the rest of the people having issues after version 1.17.0 there is now a new version 1.17.1 that might fix some of the issues you're facing.

So looks like it was a problem in version `1.17.0` but was fixed in the update `1.17.1`

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution, downgrade from the latest v1.17.0 to the previous one.
To do so follow these steps:

1. Open extension navigation
2. Right click the Vim extension
3. Select "Install another version"
4. Click on 1.16.0

Fixed it for me. Hope this works for others that may have this issue.

Comment: This fixes it but is a stop-gap solution. Thanks a lot for this. I guess I should create a github issue?